# When running Docker, it returns an error when installing PHP8.1

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker for my Laravel project. But I'm having an error installing PHP.

I had already run the project once with this same configuration and had no problems.

Error:

```
=> ERROR [14/26] RUN apt-get install -y     php8.1-fpm     php8.1-common     php8.1-curl     php8.1-mysql     php8.1-mbstring     php8.1-xml     php8.1-bcmath     php8.1-gd     php8.1-xdebug     php8.1-soap     php8  2.3s 
------
 > [14/26] RUN apt-get install -y     php8.1-fpm     php8.1-common     php8.1-curl     php8.1-mysql     php8.1-mbstring     php8.1-xml     php8.1-bcmath     php8.1-gd     php8.1-xdebug     php8.1-soap     php8.1-zip:       
#18 0.621 Reading package lists...
#18 1.822 Building dependency tree...
#18 2.008 Reading state information...
#18 2.106 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
#18 2.106 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
#18 2.106 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
#18 2.106 or been moved out of Incoming.
#18 2.106 The following information may help to resolve the situation:
#18 2.106
#18 2.106 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
#18 2.255  php8.1-fpm : Depends: systemd but it is not going to be installed or
#18 2.255                        systemd-tmpfiles but it is not installable
#18 2.275 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y     php8.1-fpm     php8.1-common     php8.1-curl     php8.1-mysql     php8.1-mbstring     php8.1-xml     php8.1-bcmath     php8.1-gd     php8.1-xdebug     php8.1-soap  
   php8.1-zip]: exit code: 100
```

My Dockerfile:

```
#------------- Setup Environment -------------------------------------------------------------

# Pull base image
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install common tools 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget curl nano htop git unzip bzip2 software-properties-common locales

# Set evn var to enable xterm terminal
ENV TERM=xterm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . ./

# Add repositories
RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABF5BD827BD9BF62
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update

#------------- Application Specific Stuff ----------------------------------------------------

# Install PHP
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    php8.1-fpm \ 
    php8.1-common \ 
    php8.1-curl \ 
    php8.1-mysql \ 
    php8.1-mbstring \ 
    php8.1-xml \
    php8.1-bcmath \
    php8.1-gd \
    php8.1-xdebug \
    php8.1-soap \
    php8.1-zip   

RUN echo "xdebug.mode=develop" >> /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini

#------------- FPM & Nginx configuration ----------------------------------------------------

# Config fpm to use TCP instead of unix socket
ADD docker/www.conf /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/php

# Install Nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

ADD docker/game /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

ADD docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

#------------- Composer & laravel configuration ----------------------------------------------------

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

#------------- Supervisor Process Manager ----------------------------------------------------

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

#------------- Container Config ---------------------------------------------------------------
ARG ENV_KEY=dev

COPY ./.${ENV_KEY}.env ./.env

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Set supervisor to manage container processes
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I already cleared the docker settings with `docker system prune -a`. I've also uninstalled and installed docker.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: Just to try it out, on the first `RUN apt-get install -y .....`, try adding `systemd` at the end (after `locales`) and tell us what happened

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:18.04` looks pretty old to me - why not use an uptodate image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 even with Ondrej PPA repository in apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920506/unable-to-install-php-7-4-on-ubuntu-16-04-even-with-ondrej-ppa-repository-in-apa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem since August 2, looks like something wrong with `ondrej/php` repository.
First, I tried to install `systemd` as @matiaslauriti suggested, but the following error has occured:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
[07:33:33]#24 7.480  systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 237-3ubuntu10.53) but 237-3ubuntu10.54 is to be installed
```

That problem has been fixed by adding the following to `sources.list`:

```
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You don't need install `systemd` explicitly, it will be installed as one of `php` dependency.

Comment: "looks like something wrong" - then why not report this in the bug tracker at https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I needed a quick fix for this bug, why don't you post the bug report yourself?

Comment: I ihaven't experienced any problem, but you :) And getting this fixed could also help others. That could be a nice thing, as you are using stuff that other people (like Ondrej) manage for free for others